# How to get list of checked checkbox from jsp form

Tags: spring-mvc, radio-button

I am trying to assign some subjects to a course in below code. I am using springmvc framework.

The webpage looks like this -
**http://oi59.tinypic.com/28qrpeh.jpg**

What i want that if someone check some subjects in webpage i should able to get the list of those chosen subjects. I tried to search for the example but not able to find any. If some one can help me with it would me really appriciated.

```
<form:form commandName="course">
    <c:forEach items="${subjectList}" var="subject">
        <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="subject2" value="${subject.id}" /> ${subject.name }</td>
        </tr>
    </c:forEach>
</form:form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that with getParameterValues("subject2") which will return an array of String.
then you loop through them, for instance

```
String[] Answers = request.getParameterValues("subject2");
 PrintWriter out=response.getWriter();
 for(int i =0; i<Answers.length; i++){
    out.print(Answers[i]+ "<br>");
     }
```